# Using and displaying number as it is inserted in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have invoice table which holds invoice number which starts from 0 e.g. "**120**"

So how can I preserve **Inv_Num** column zero with leading when the data is displayed too?. So that when it is displayed  looks like "**0000120**".

I have defined my table so far:

```
Create Table Invoice_Report(Inv_Num int not null, Inv_Date date, orderNum int not null)
```

Any help, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You don't need to store leading zeroes in the table. You can use query to format the data and display according to your needs.

Comment: Good. So how can I display the specified column values with leading zero, can you show me?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you want total output length of 7 characters, you can pad leading zeros as below:

```
select RIGHT(cast('0000' + col as varchar(3)), 7) from someTable
```

Answer (score 1):

An `int` is a data type that contains a numerical value. "0000120" is a representation of such number. That is not the same.

If you want to have a representational value, use a string, or in SQL Server, `varchar(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Padding of numbers solves the issue:

```
SELECT Inv_Num = REPLACE(STR(Inv_Num, 7), SPACE(1), '0') FROM Invoice
```

Read more here: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/pad/